# Scanner input reading multiple lines of code at once, throws IntputMismatchException

Tags: java

Okay so, I have this piece of code:

```
if (type == 1){
            System.out.println("Agency name: ");
            agencyName = in.nextLine();


            System.out.println("No. of days: ");
            days = in.nextInt();


            Patuvanje p = new PraznicnoPatuvanje (agencyName, 20, days);
            nizaPatuvanje[i] = p;
        }
```

The scanner is reading 'agencyName' and 'days' without me trying to input the agencyName at first. What code should I add so that the compiler would wait until I initialize the agencyName variable, and then let me assign the 'days' variable.

This is how it looks like in the Console:

[image]

Comment: write an `in.nextLine();` after `agencyName = in.nextLine();`

Comment: provide complete code all scanner you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code preceding this, you are reading the `number of vacations`

After doing this you are pressing `Enter`  This needs to be consumed too.

Change your code to

```
in.nextLine (); // comse previouslt entered `Enter`
System.out.println("Agency name: ");
agencyName = in.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (type == 1){
                    System.out.println("Agency name: ");
                    agencyName = in.nextLine();
                    in.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("No. of days: ");
                    days = in.nextInt();



                    Patuvanje p = new PraznicnoPatuvanje (agencyName, 20, days);
                    nizaPatuvanje[i] = p;


  }
```

try this